# Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution average speed and second-order moment

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, physics, mathematical-physics

Someone can give me a link where I can find the solution step by step of the following integrals. Otherwise,if there is someone so kind to solve them.

$$dN(v)=4\pi N(\frac{m}{2\pi kT})^{\frac{3}{2}}e^{\frac{-mv^{2}}{2kT}}v^{2}dv$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }vdN(v)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}v_{p}$$
$$\sqrt{\int_{0}^{\infty }v^{2}dN(v)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}v_{p}$$

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: In the first equation, what is $N$ on the right hand side?

Comment: It is the number of molecules.

Comment: Then you should change the letter, because $N(v)$ is your distribution and $N$ is the number of molecules, which are different. And by the way, these integrals are solved in any college physics textbook, so what's the problem?

Comment: I know that there are on college physics textbook but  I have not a book about this topic for this reason I asked a link, because I didn't find it.

Comment: Get rid of all the unnecessary constants, then you will have integrals $$\int_0^\infty v^3 e^{-a v^2} dx$$ and $$\int_0^\infty v^4 e^{-a v^2} dx$$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: That's supposed to be $dv$ inside the integrals, of course